# Maven dependency for javax.ejb.jar into .m2 directory

Tags: java, maven, jakarta-ee, jar

I cant find `javax.ejb.jar` in my .m2 dirctory, I need this jar for `import javax.ejb.Schedule;` , here is my pom file entry.

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>javax.ejb</groupId>
            <artifactId>ejb-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
```

I am not sure if it will work or not, or its a right way to do things. Can some one please help to make a change in the `POM` file so that it downloads `javax.ejb.jar` into the `.m2` directory.

**Updated**

1. by `.m2` I mean in the repository directory in the correct folder
   hierarchy (What ever it is).
2. Why? We have multiple sub projects (In eclipse workspace), In order to resolve dependency we use **M2_REPO**/path/to/the/required_library_file.jar, Now theses projects are part of code bases, Every developer download the source code, Maven download all jar to the repository directory(of the developer using any OS/Platform). This relative path from `M2_REPO` helps developer to have consitenat code (for eclipse project). Otherwise everyone will be adding their own path.

If it still doesn't make sense, here is what I want, Please give me an entry for POM file which download the javax.ejb.jar file into .m2 directory what ever the sub path is.

I have to include this jar in every project manually (And every developer needs to them as well from what ever directory have glassfish (C: , D:, E:, or /home/glassfish/modules/)

```
D:\servers\glassfish-3.1.2\glassfish3\glassfish\modules\javax.ejb.jar
```

where rest of the jars in each project are included as `M2_REPO/path/to/jar` which makes less no changes in the code base to commit.

```
M2_REPO/javax/ejb/ejb-api/3.0/ejb-api-3.0.jar
M2_REPO/javax/enterprise/cdi-api/1.0-SP1/cdi-api-1.0-SP1.jar
M2_REPO/javax/inject/javax.inject/1/javax.inject-1.jar
```

etc etc

Comment: what is the error when you do `mvn clean compile -e` ?

Comment: Why do you want in your `.m2` directory? Usually it gets downloaded to `.m2/repository/<path to artifact>`

Comment: http://findjar.com/jar/org/apache/openejb/ejb31-api-experimental/3.1.1/ejb31-api-experimental-3.1.1.jar.html (not sure how useful, but findjar.com or maven dependency search in IDE are nice.

Comment: what is your issue i mean is project showing error that class not found?

Comment: Can you show the entire POM? Have you added the dependency under dependencies?

Comment: You propably may change the scope to `compile` (simply out-comment the scope).

Comment: @JoopEggen The scope is not the problem here.

Comment: Wouldn't you need to search for a file called ejb-api-3.0.jar in a folder structure of /javax/ejb in your repository..? Clearly there would be no javax.ejb.jar

Comment: Yes @NielsBechNielsen you are right, As dependency for `javax.ejb.Schedule` lead me to `javax.ejb.jar` so I am looking a way to add this jar to repository.

Comment: Sounds like you need to setup a project directory using nexus: http://www.sonatype.org/nexus/

Comment: On another comment. You really should consider using m2eclipse to manage the classpath in eclipse. If you do so, you do not need to manually update classpaths in eclipse, as it reads and updates from the pom.

Answer (score 1):

I think I hear what you mean now :)

The maven dependency you specify

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>javax.ejb</groupId>
  <artifactId>ejb-api</artifactId>
  <version>3.0</version>
  <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

which you have in `.m2/repository/javax/ueb/ejb-api/3.0/ejb-api-3.0.jar` does not contain the class/interface `javax.ejb.Schedule`.

But you found the jar-file in your glassfish server, which does contain `javax.ejb.Schedule`and its name is `D:\servers\glassfish-3.1.2\glassfish3\glassfish\modules\javax.ejb.jar` and now you ask how to get that into the pom?

Well, the Java EE APIs and their official jars in maven are somewhat a study in disharmony.
If you run a search on [maven central](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Cfc%3A%20javax.ejb.Schedule) you will find multiple jars containing exactly that class. You will probably note that all appserver vendors provide their own edition of every aspect of every api in every version.

You should be able to find a jar with the javax.ejb module from glassfish in version 3.1.2

```
http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails|org.glassfish|javax.ejb|3.1.2|jar
```

in which case the dependency would be

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
  <artifactId>javax.ejb</artifactId>
  <version>3.1.2</version>
  <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Yes you are perfectly right my friend. However maven is unable to locate it
`[artifact:dependencies] Unable to locate resource in repository
[artifact:dependencies] [INFO] Unable to find resource 'org.glassfish:javax.ejb:
pom:3.1.2' in repository JBoss repository (http://repository.jboss.org/nexus/con
tent/groups/public/) ` etc

Comment: So it tells you that it is could not find it in JBoss repository, which is not maven central. For some reason I suspect you have a user adapted settings.xml for your maven installation.

Comment: If you browse the JBOSS repository http://repository.jboss.org/nexus/ you can search for javax.ejb.Schedule there as well. I did find it in a package called org.glassfish.main.ejb:javax.ejb:3.1.2

Answer (score 0):

I found [another artifactId here](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.ejb/javax.ejb-api/3.2), though maven has your version too.
A (very) weird maven caching problem? Then it might work tomorrow.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.ejb</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.ejb-api</artifactId>
    <version>3.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Though this is a new version, for compilation it should do.

Answer (score -1):

You may need to provide the repository location in your pom.xml file or in .m2/settings.xml file for the required jar to get downloaded into .m2 directory.

Comment: No need to do so cause it's in [Maven Central](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cgav%7C1%7Cg%3A%22javax.ejb%22%20AND%20a%3A%22ejb-api%22).

Answer (score -3):

The dependency is declared as provided what means that the container will provide it.

What container are you using? I think Tomcat/Jetty won't provide that jar as it seems so Java EE. In that case just change the scope to `compile`.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>javax.ejb</groupId>
  <artifactId>ejb-api</artifactId>
  <version>3.0</version>
  <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```

More info about dependency scopes:
http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Dependency_Scope

Comment: This does not explain why the jar is not being downloaded.

Comment: Yes it does. The scope `provided` means that Maven won't download the jar because it's already in the container classpath. If you want to download the jar change it to `compile` or `runtime`

Comment: No, it doesn't. The provided scope means the jar will not be bundled with the application when its final structure is created. It will still be downloaded and available for compiling.

Comment: @polypiel not true at all. Provided means that someone else (the container in this case) will provide it at RUNTIME. Provided will still download the dependency in order to COMPILE against it.

Comment: @PeterLiljenberg Totally agree.